# PHP Laravel Task Scheduling Best Practice

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, cron, task

I am building a simple application that will schedule an ad set to be enabled / disabled based on the time the user inputs.

For example, a user may want to have their ads run from 6 AM - 9 AM and then 5 PM - 10 PM and off at all other times.

What would be the best way to schedule this? I would store all of data in MYSQL, should I have a cron/task that checks every minute for the rows in the table that match the time and then the function enable/disable?

To continue with the example, the table might contain columns, time, function.

6 AM, enable
9 AM, disable
5 PM, enable
10 PM, disable

My question is if I have 10,000 users or so, would this be too much for the web server or is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: I'm not sure you need a scheduled task at all, but maybe I'm missing something. Couldn't you just check a table to see if the current time is in their scheduled time when getting the ad to display?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the below approach, what we are doing is...

1. There are 2 tables - `ads` and `ad_timings` which saves different **start_time** and **end_time** for each ad...
2. Where are saving **start_time** like **0600** and **end_time** like **0900**. So, now you'll simply check if the current time (say, its `2016-23-12 06:50:11`)... You convert that to `0650`.
3. Now you find out all ads where the **start_time** is less than **650** and **end_time** is more than that to find out active ads and do the reverse for ads to stop.
4. Run it every 10 mins... Give each user a minimum input time interval of 10 mins... This way you run cron every 10 mins and also save memory in the background....

Your tables

```
ad
id | name | current_status | ....
 1 |  ... |      0         | .....

ad_timings
id | ad_id | start_time | end_time
1  |   1   |   600      |  900
1  |   1   |   1700     |  2200
```

Your models

```
class Ad extends Model
{
  public function timings()
  {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\AdTimings');
  }
}

class AdTimings extends Model
{
  protected $table = 'ad_timings';

  public function ad()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Ad')
  }
}
```

In your scheduler

```
use Carbon\Carbon;
use App\Models\Ad;

class AdScheduler
{
  public function handle()
  {
    $now = Carbon::now();

    // This will convert current timestamp to something like
    // Timestamp: 2016-12-23 23:36:11
    // to
    // Now: 2336
    // Basically you are calculating time on the basis of hundreds..
    // Like people say... 1300 hours... get me?
    $now = $now->hour . $now->minute;

    // These are the ads to run
    // You can change their current_status field to 1 with update
    $adsToRun = Ad::whereHas('timings', function($query) use ($now) {
                  return $query->where('start_time', '<=', $now)
                               ->where('end_time', '>=', $now)
                })->get();

    // Ads to Stop
    // You can change their current_status field to 0 with update
    $adsToStop = Ad::whereHas('timings', function($query) use ($now) {
                  return $query->where('start_time', '>=', $now)
                               ->where('end_time', '<=', $now)
                })->get();
  }
}
```